# How to get prometheus metrics using c++?

Tags: prometheus

> I am trying to get the required prometheus metrics values using c++ code. For example, i need to execute the currently running metrics query "go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"}" using c++ code and get the value of the query.
>   If somebody having sample projects kindly share and assist me.

Comment: Q: Do you have a Prometheus SDK for C++?  Per the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/), it appears the "official" SDKs are only for Go, Java, Scala, Python and Ruby.  Q: If you have a C/C++ library - which one is it?  Where did you get it?  Do they have documentation for their library?

Comment: I tried with unofficial third party client library which is mentioned in the same page itself, "https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp" but this source is not working as expected...

Comment: Prometheus' HTTP API is documented at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/. I haven't used C++ and definitely haven't used it with REST APIs and JSON, but use whatever library allows you to make HTTP REST requests, it shouldn't be all that difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

The way I get prometheus metrics using c++ is like this:

1. Select a client library for modern c++, https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp  it is a good choice.
2. Create a exposer(actually a http server), like `Exposer exposer{"127.0.0.1:8080"};`
3. Create a metrics registry, like `auto registry = std::make_shared<Registry>();`
4. Set value or get value

> ```
> std::map<std::string, std::string> labels; 
>
> labels.insert(make_pair("quantile", "0")); 
>
> auto &counter_family = BuildCounter().Name('go_gc_duration_seconds').Register(*registry_ptr_);
>
>
> auto &metric_counter = counter_family.Add(labels);
> ```

we can use http api to get value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'll need to make the http request, and parse the json to extract the results. This can be done quite easily using e.g.

- [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)
- and [nlohman/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)